# Get User's details using Sitecore SocialConnected module

Tags: c#, facebook, sitecore, sitecore-social-connected

I'm trying to connect to my Facebook account using Sitecore Social Connected module. After logging in, I'll have to display User's details on my site.

I've used `connectedUserManager.LogOnUser` and `connectedUserManager.AttachUser` method. But, my database doesn't get details of the Facebook user updated in it. What might be missing? How to retrieve user information, after I'm successfully logged in using Facebook credentials.

```
const bool IsAsyncProfileUpdate = true; 
const string ApplicationItemId = "{A9987983-D946-4E53-8FE4-1EB8BE650B43}"; 
ConnectUserManager connectUserManager = new ConnectUserManager();      

if(!Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated) {  
  connectUserManager.LoginUser("Facebook",IsAsyncProfileUpdate, ApplicationItemId); 
} 
else { 
  connectUserManager.AttachUser("Facebook", IsAsyncProfileUpdate, ApplicationItemId); 
}
```

Comment: You have to show some code and elaborate your problem. How can we just help you just like that!

Comment: const bool IsAsyncProfileUpdate = true;
            const string ApplicationItemId = "{A9987983-D946-4E53-8FE4-1EB8BE650B43}";
            ConnectUserManager connectUserManager = new ConnectUserManager(); 

            if(!Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                connectUserManager.LoginUser("Facebook",IsAsyncProfileUpdate, ApplicationItemId);
            }
            else
            {
                connectUserManager.AttachUser("Facebook", IsAsyncProfileUpdate, ApplicationItemId);
            }

Comment: Sorry, code didn't get posted in proper format. Does that makes any sense?

Comment: @Chandana, you'd rather edit your question to add the code than posting it to a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can access all user information pulled in from facebook by looping through the custom profile properties.
Please have a look at this blog: [Social Connected with Sitecore (Facebook) 2: Access facebook information](http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/social-connected-with-sitecore-facebook-2-access-facebook-information/)